# Dynamixels (AX-12A) no longer detected after id change

Tags: python, dynamixel

I have 8 dynamixels that are connected together. Everything worked fine until I changed all their ids to 200,201,202, ... To change their ids, I used [this python library](https://github.com/HumaRobotics/dynamixel_hr). Now, none of my motors are detected. I tried testing one motor at a time and I have the same results for all motors.

I tried running `factory_reset.py` from [DynamixelSDK](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/DynamixelSDK/blob/master/python/tests/protocol1_0/factory_reset.py) and the script returned:

> Succeeded to open the port
>
> Succeeded to change the baudrate Now the controller baudrate is : 1000000
>
> [ID:001] Try factoryreset :
>
> Aborted
>
> [TxRxResult] There is no status packet!

Any idea why I have this error, and how I can fix this? Thank you.

Comment: you did not say how you changed the IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a for loop with all possible ids until it is detected.